# Is it possible to hide my Mac(s) from network-connected other Mac(s)?

Tags: finder, network, sharing

I always connect my MacBook Pro to my network, and also some of other Macs. Recently, our boss hired a new guy, that currently has no privileges to see other Mac's data and such. I thought I could hide them like Windows can (by setting network privacy to public or something), and it seems to be [possible](https://superuser.com/questions/154108/how-do-you-hide-a-computer-name-on-a-network-os-x-10-6).

However, that question's answer says that,

> In terms of the Finder, make sure File Sharing, Remote Management and Screen Sharing are all unchecked and your computer won't appear in another user's sidebar.

So it seems that I have to turn off the File Sharing. Problem is that we need to have that. While the new guy doesn't have privileges to see data, some of the files are crucial to our job, and these are not restricted to him (and they're placed in separated folder). While we could give that to him via USB memory or something, we'd like it to be stay updated, since that file is our customer's information and something like that.

Windows is very good at handling the situation like this. Even if they're hidden from explorer's side bar, user can still connect to them by using the IP address. It seems to be Mac isn't able to do so.

Is there any way to hide Mac while having file sharing enabled? If not, what could be alternative method?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are trying to achieve, you're saying you don't want them to access files on your Mac but they have to access files on your Mac. You want to share only a limited number of files with him, while sharing other files with other users? If that's the case create separate folders, add them to file sharing, and specify which users can access each of the folders. However if multiple people need to edit the same file (e.g. spreadsheet) then it's probably not a good idea to use file sharing for that, as people can overwrite others' changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Windows is very good at handling the situation like this. Even if they're hidden from explorer's side bar, user can still connect to them by using the IP address. It seems to be Mac isn't able to do so.

Windows does this through Firewall rules - it blocks protocols like WINS, NetBIOS, Discovery, etc. macOS can do this as well with the pf firewall.

However, (IMO) this is pointless. To hide your computer only to deliberately hand out the IP is like paying the phone company for a number that shows up as “blocked” to be hidden only to post your number on a billboard; it’s counterintuitive.  If you’re on a public Wi-Fi, then this (turning off network discovery) is very much desirable.

Instead, you should be focusing on sharing permissions and access control lists. Personally, I would get a NAS (start small) that has these functions built in and easy to implement. This way the availability of your Mac is not necessary for the “new guy” to do his work.

Comment: I thought of using NAS but for some reason our boss said no :c I should have stated that in my post. At some point in future he might say yes so I'll tell him the merit of using NAS from time to time. While doing so, I guess I'll have to play with firewall...